# Material color is darker in Kd in .mtl file than it is in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, export

I'm using Cycles Render and exporting my model as `.obj` and `.mtl` files. I have a simple green diffuse material, but in the `.mtl` file, the color becomes a much darker green. The viewport color and the material color are the same (I know that the wavefront obj/mtl files use the viewport color).

It SHOULD be `Kd 0.121568 0.364705 0.149019` (hex `#1F5D26`)

but it's exporting as `Kd 0.010962 0.087569 0.015506` (hex `#031604` [image: dark] )

Why is this happening?

---

`.mtl` file:

```
newmtl PineTree.001
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.010962 0.087569 0.015506
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

---

Blender material:

[image: Blender material]

Comment: You are going to need to research colour management, and in particular transfer functions. Also note that Cycles is a scene referred model, which means your notions of 0.0 being black and 1.0 being white are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Troy said it's a color management convertion.
In cycles colors aren't bounded to 0/1 range, this is scene referred datas.
In .mtl files colors are stored in a 0/1 range, the display referred datas.
Look the Wiki for description of [Wavefront .obj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file), scroll down to the section "Material template library" and subsection "Basic materials"
It's said that : "Color definitions are in RGB where each channel's value is between 0 and 1."

So with that in mind you couldn't expect a 1/1 between Cycles internal values and exported bounded values. Plus I don't know if you're aware that Hex values are gamma corrected in Blender.
It looks like there is a transfere curve, I guess an EOTF curve, see here for more details : [the-importance-of-terminology-and-srgb-uncertainty](http://colour-science.org/posts/the-importance-of-terminology-and-srgb-uncertainty/), the whole article is worth reading but there is a section about the sRGB EOTF transfer curve.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I could correct for this? The difference in color is pretty striking

Comment: You could use the OpenColorIO Python bindings and roll the data properly through the correct transform. That would be an ideal, and a second less ideal solution would be to roll a custom sRGB EOTF function.

Comment: I would add that for this topic knowledge is essential.

Comment: Thank you both. I think I'm going to manually edit the mtl files. It's not worth it for me to spend the time learning about this and then write an algorithm to fix it. This must be a bug with blender.

Comment: These are pretty unsatisfactory answers. I'm using Blender to model for Color 3D printing, and it's tendancy to take skin tones and transform them because it's "right" is just wrong. If assign a material #C39B7F, I expect #C39B7F, not #8B5436, which is what I'm getting.

I've tried fixing the color curves, I've tried adjusting the scene's gamma correction, but whatever I do I can not get a 1-to-1 predictable color.

Comment: Yes these answers didn't satisfy you, does it means that they aren't good?
When you understand how light works, you can't say what you've just said.
Cycles is based on real physics (doesn't means that it's 100% real), so say to mother nature that she doesn't satisfy you^^.

Comment: Ask yourself how would you perfectly match a real color with painting.
You are the only one to see what you see, how you see. For so many reasons.
Your eyes and your brain interpret the colors, you are unique, so the colors you see are unique. And what is the real color you see? The one you see in the morning, the afternoon, the night, inside, outside? Filmic is a tool, yes it looks like a magic button, but if you don't understand how light works you can't blame others. For 3D print if you use filmic blindly you shoot yourself in the foot, stay in default (clamped sRGB).